# Jquery.Validate -> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I thought I just made a mistake in my rules, but this error has me baffled!

```
 TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'validator.settings["on"+event.type].call(validator,this[0])')
```

I wrote a separate custom rule below first that uses the jquery.payment library to validate the CC number.  It appears to be jquery.validate.min that is throwing the error though!  Anyone any idea?

Here are my rules:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("jqPaymentCreditCard",
   function(value, element) {
   return this.optional(element) || 

$.payment.validateCardNumber(value);
        }, 
        " Invalid credit card number.");

    $("#SSLForm").validate(
    {        
        onkeyup: true,
        errorClass: "is-invalid",       
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.attr("name") == "KKMonth" ) {
                error.insertAfter("#KKYear");
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        rules: {

            CreditCardHolder: { required: true },
            KKnr: { required: true , jqPaymentCreditCard: true},
            KKMonth: { required: true },
            KKYear: { required: true },
            CCCVC: { required: true, digits: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 4 }
        },
        messages: {
            CreditCardHolder: { required: $("#CreditCardHolderRequiredHdn").val() },
            KKnr: { required: $("#KKnrRequiredHdn").val(), jqPaymentCreditCard: $("#KKnrRequiredHdn").val() },
            KKMonth: { required: $("#KKMonthRequiredHdn").val() },
            KKYear: { required: $("#KKYearRequiredHdn").val() },
            CCCVC: { required: $("#CCCVCRequiredHdn").val(), digits: $("#CCCVCDigitsHdn").val(), minlength: $("#CCCVCDigitsHdn").val(), maxlength: $("#CCCVCDigitsHdn").val() }
        },
       tooltip_options: {
                CreditCardHolder: {placement: 'right' },
                KKnr: { placement: 'right' },
                KKMonth: { placement: 'right' },
                KKYear: { placement: 'right' },
                CCCVC: { placement: 'right' }
       }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.  `onkeyup: true,`**

[As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onkeyup), `true` is not a valid value for the `onkeyup` option.  The plugin's `keyup` behavior is enabled by default and you can only use `false` or an over-riding function.  Setting this option to `true` can lead to unpredictable results.  You'll need to remove this line entirely if you don't want to disable it.

**2.  `tooltip_options:`**

There is no such option for the `.validate()` method called `tooltip_options`.  Best case, this option is doing nothing.

Please refer to [the official documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) for the only options you're allowed to use within `.validate()` and their designated settings.

Comment: Thanks Sparky!!  The 1st thing I think is the reason I am going to try it now.

The second one is a separate jquery.validate.bootstrap.tooltip plugin for showing tooltips as error messages so I dont think that is causing any issues as these are working.

Comment: @user1957687, if tooltips are working, it is absolute NOT because you put `tooltip_options` inside of `.validate()`.   That parameter is totally **meaningless** in this context.

Comment: @user1957687, you're welcome.  Remove `tooltip_options` from `.validate()` to prove to yourself that it's not doing anything.

Comment: @user1957687, if that's the case, I'd love to see it.  Can you demonstrate in a jsFiddle?  Thanks!

Comment: Im under a bit of pressure at the moment in work, but ill put up an example over the weekend if that is ok?

Comment: @user1957687, looking forward to it.